# Does Intel Core 2 T5500 @ 1.66GHz support Virtualization Tech?

Tags: virtualization, intel-core2

It says so on [Intel's website](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=27253), but when I used Intel Processor ID Utility to check it, the report said no. And I couldn't use XP Mode in Windows 7 because "the hardware does not support virtualization tech." I know little about CPU, so my 2nd question is, can this be solved?

Comment: What brand and model of machine is this?

Comment: it's HP dv6065ea

Answer (score 1):

That processor does support VT, so it is likely disabled in your BIOS.  You should check your BIOS and enable VT there.

Comment: thank you, but how can I do that?

Comment: This is a different model, but may have similar instructions.

Poke around a bit, and you'll probably recognize something.

http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?threadId=1120296

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Intel Virtualization Technology List](http://ark.intel.com/VTList.aspx) it does. You may however require a BIOS update from [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=3214013&lang=en&) to enable the extensions, as most Notebooks ship with this disabled and no option in the stock BIOS to enable it.